Meaning of msg.sender in constructor
What is the meaning of a msg.sender in a constructor? Is it strictly the owner of a contract or any EOA account calling the contract?

In a constructor, actually msg.sender refers to the address that deployed the contract to the blockchain. It's not limited to the contract's owner, but any account that initiated the deployment transaction.

Thanks Ahmad , This really answer my question

Happy to assist you.
